# `__cpp` and gcc inline ARM assembler

Tags: c++, assembly, arm

```
asm("ldr r6, [r0, #__cpp(offsetof(X, y))]\t\n");
```

I am unable to compile the above in-line assembly line using following command:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -c -lm -pg -O1 -g -pipe -fno-common \
  -fno-builtin -Wall  -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp \
  -mthumb-interwork -mtune=cortex-a9
```

The error log is :

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:74: Error: ']' expected -- \
      `ldr r6,[r0,#__cpp(offsetof(VP8BitReader,buf_))]'
```

Apparently `__cpp` is unrecognized. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems `__cpp` is a keyword [available for RealView assembler](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205f/Chdbhjcc.html).
GNU toolchain doesn't have it, I suggest using [Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) syntax to pass something from C to inline assembly.

Comment: `asm("ldr r6, [r0, %0]\n" : "J" (offsetof(X, y)) : : "r6", "r0");` although it is probably better to let the compiler assign the `r0` and `r6` value by annotating them as well.  My point is that 'J' is the specifier for this.

Answer (score 2):

See code below for a possible solution however you probably need to check [Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) documentation (or some other [tutorial](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html)) for writing correct inline assembly with GCC.

`offsetof` for GCC is called [__builtin_offsetof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html), however you invoke GCC with [-fno-builtin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) which makes your intention unclear in this case (that doesn't disable offsetof).

```
$ cat foo.c 
typedef struct {
    int pad[32];
    void *buf_;
} VP8BitReader;

void bar() {
    asm volatile("ldr r6, [r0, %[offset]]\t\n" : /* output */ : /* input */ [offset] "J" (__builtin_offsetof(VP8BitReader, buf_)) : /* clobber */ "r6", "r0");
}
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -S -fno-common -fno-builtin -Wall foo.c
$ cat foo.s 
<skipped>
#APP
@ 7 "foo.c" 1
    ldr r6, [r0, #128]  
<skipped>
```